# mongodb update data from string to sub-object using shell command

Tags: mongodb

I would like to run an update command to mongodb that will update all the info inside of an collection.
in mysql i will just do :

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

How can I achive this in mongodb? so far this is what I have :

```
db.property.update(
   {
      $set: {"image":{"isHosted": false, "imageUrl": "", "imageMediumUrl": "", "imageThumbUrl": ""}}
   }
)
```

This is what my current property looks:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("54183b8ee8643951f6b3ee0f"),
   "image": "http: \/\/img.com\/California\/Properties\/JPG_Main\/341\/3513341.jpg",
}
```

Thanks in advance, hope someone can help me as a newbie with mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a clause to your set statement.  You need the equivalent of the where clause.

IE:

```
 db.property.update( { image: "http:\/\/img.com\/California\/Properties\/JPG_Main\/341\/3513341.jpg"},
   {
      $set: {"image":{"isHosted": false, "imageUrl": "", "imageMediumUrl": "", "imageThumbUrl": ""}}
   }
)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply betsey, how about if I want to target all data? that's why I did not add the { image: "http:\/\/img.com\/California\/Properties\/JPG_Main\/341\/3513341.jpg"},

Comment: Just leave the first argument of `update` empty `{}`. This is an empty query clause which matches all documents.